# xblock make install errors

Tags: openedx, edx

Im trying to create an xblock and im following the guide [here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/xblock-tutorial/en/latest/getting_started/create_first_xblock.html#id14)
when i try to run `make install` on a fresh project it just does not work this is what the gist of my error messageon terminal looks like :

```
    ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/xblock_development/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cg/fmbpjgr974v64fpgfq_dr49c0000gn/T/pip-install-69b7awb9/lxml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cg/fmbpjgr974v64fpgfq_dr49c0000gn/T/pip-install-69b7awb9/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cg/fmbpjgr974v64fpgfq_dr49c0000gn/T/pip-record-m5mlsogy/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/xblock_development/env/include/site/python3.7/lxml Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: can you check the logs and post here so we can see ?

Comment: sorry what do mean logs like workbench logs?